# Determine currently executing method

Tags: c#, events, clr, autoresetevent

**Assume the following code**

```
private AutoResetEvent m_MethodDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void Method1()
{
    // Do something
    Method2();
}

private void Method2()
{
    // All done
    m_MethodDone.Set();
}

private void Method3()
{
}

private void Program()
{
    Task t = New Task(() => { // Code In Question
        m_MethodDone.WaitOne()
        Method3();
    });

    t.Start();
    // Do other things.
}
```

**Question**

Is there a way to "capture" CLR events, be it from an event or loop in my thread?

```
if(SomeRunTimeThing.LastMethodExecuted.Name == "Method2")
     Method3();
```

**Why**

I don't want to have to write call hooks into the guts of the software, this is an *observable* problem (hmm ideas are coming...) (it actually observes the UI calling pattern for automation type functionality).

Comment: You already have a signal setup.  What more do you need?

Comment: Good question. I'd like to hook into more methods, so I'd end up with quite a few AutoResetEvents. Plus it'd feel better to have a system to observe something that's already occurring as opposed to signaling what's happened every time. And also because I wanted to know if this is possible :)

Comment: You might be able to do it with [Caller Info Attributes](http://bartwullems.blogspot.ca/2012/02/c-5-caller-info-attributes.html) though you may need to redesign the code. You can also make use of the StackTrace class and crawl up its frames, though this is costly in terms of performance (I think) and you need to be careful about compiler optimizations which may in-line your method code.

Comment: The only thing that I know of that does exactly what you are looking for is the unmanaged Profiling API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384493.aspx) which isn't going to help you.  Just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this scenario is not supported by the CLR.

If it were, this would lead to all sorts of complications. For example, note that the compiler might *inline* your private method, so the actual code might look more like this:

```
private void Method1()
{
    // Body of Method 1
    // Body of Method 2
}
```

In that case `SomeRunTimeThing.LastMethodExecuted.Name` never takes the value `Method2`. (That's also the reason why you should never use stack trace information for anything but logging and debugging.)

Comment: Excellent point there, inlining isn't something I thought of. Perhaps the only way to go is individual signals.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand: it is necessary to determine the last method called without changing code of methods.
the one solution comes to mind: use interception for all classes in socope. And in interception code store what method was called.

**UPD**
for example you could use unity, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660861%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I figured this will probably be the case, and attributing every method is the only answer. It could be referenced in a dictionary via the method name too, so you'd call dict["Method2"].WaitOne(). UPD: Excellent thanks, I'll have a read of that now :)

Comment: actually in some case you don't need attributes. You just need to resolve your class instance from container that configurated to intercept some methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to trace what calls were made after the fact, but you *can* see what method called a particular method. Perhaps you can use the call stack to solve your problem. See http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-callstack/ for an example.